# Put span within f.submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This may be simpe but cant seem to get it working. I have the following submit button

```
<%= f.submit 'Send Message', class: 'btn submit', id: 'validForm' %>
```

and I want to put an icomoon image within the button

```
<span class="icon-envelope"></span>
```

But how do i get the span class within the button.. ?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [button_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag) and put the span within the button in that way

```
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn submit", id: 'validForm') do %>
 <span class="icon-envelope"></span> Send Message
<% end %>
```

Comment: ah just beat me to it, i was playing with the button_tag, though i done f.button.. whats the difference? :-)

Comment: The button tag allows richer labels such as images and emphasis, so this helper will also accept a block. I normally use this helper when I want to add content inside. Cheers :)